# How to hide or remove ajax api calls from Network section of a browser?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, networking, browser, fetch

I am working on a website which is developed in react js and I am fetching all data through the API calls. That API calls are visible in the network section of a browser and that API call contains JWT token in the header part of all API call, So it can cause security issue due to that anyone can do that API call with the same header and same URL through other platforms like postman n all.

So my question is that how can I control that no one else is able to access it or how can I hide that API calls from the network section of the browser?

Is there any other solution to solve this security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to assign a token to each user. The token will be given to the user upon authentication.
2. You have to manage access to the page based on the userId and token.
3. Yo should not use generic tokens for all the users.
4. Destroy the token upon user logout.

If the user see the token on the network they can only have access to the portion that he is suppose to have access.

This is how I do it, hope it helps.